# Show that $R[\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z] \cong R[x] / (x^n - 1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, ring-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite cyclic group of order $n$ with generator $g$. Given a ring $R$, then the group algebra over $R$ is isomorphic to $R[x] / (x^n - 1)$.

How to prove this simple fact? Surely the map $x \mapsto g$ contains $(x^n - 1)$ in its kernel, but how to show that they are equivalent. I thought some "dimension-type" argument would work, as if the kernel is "to big" we would have  a different number of generators, but as the rank of a module is in general not unique (as written [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Free_module)) this argument will not work...

Comment: Free modules of equal rank are still isomorphic as $R$-modules even if it is possible that free modules of distinct ranks may also be isomorphic (over some rings). So that's not a problem. Just prove that the obvious isomorphism is an isomorphism of rings and you are done.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3215755/construction-of-rings-rn-times-given-a-ring-r-times-and-a-natura?noredirect=1#comment6616758_3215755

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Use polynomial division by $x^n-1$, which is monic.

Comment: How would that help in proving that if something is zero under the map $x \mapsto g$, then it must be a multiple of $x^n - 1$?