# Construction of rings $(R^n,+,\times)$, given a ring $(R,+,\times)$ and a natural $n\ge 2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This is a development of a [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3206168/minimal-requirements-to-get-a-ring-rn-times-from-a-ring-r?noredirect=1#comment6599258_3206168) of mine, now with a more focused question at the end.

---

Let $R$ be a commutative ring (throughout this post, by "ring" I'll mean not necessarily an "associative ring"). If we denote by $+$ the addition component-wise, we get that $(R^n,+)$ is an abelian group ($n$ integer, $n \ge 2$) with additive unit $\bar 0:=(0,0,\dots,0)$. If we further request:

- $R$ with unit $1$;
- $(R^n,+)$ left $R$-module

then $\forall \bar u \in R^n, \bar u = u^i\bar e_i$ (summation convention), where $\bar e_i:=(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0)$ (the only $1$ is in the *i*-th entry).

Now, suppose that we want to build up in $R^n$ a multiplication, $\times$, such that:

- $(R^n,+,\times)$ is a ring, namely $\times$ is distributive with $+$;
- $\times$ is bilinear on $R$.

Then, $\bar e_i \times \bar e_j=\alpha_{ij}^k\bar e_k$ completely defines the multiplication under construction.

Within this general formulation, we can get at least ($\delta_m^l$ is Kronecker's symbol):

1. **Direct product of $n$ copies of $R$**. This is the case for: $$\alpha_{ij}^k=\delta_i^k\delta_j^k \tag 1$$ The element $\bar e \in R^n$ is multiplicative unit if and only if:
   \begin{alignat}{1}
   \bar e_j=\bar e \times \bar e_j=e^i\bar e_i \times \bar e_j=e^i\alpha_{ij}^k\bar e_k, \forall j &\Leftrightarrow e^i\alpha_{ij}^k=\delta_j^k, \forall j,k \\
   &\Leftrightarrow e^i\delta_i^k\delta_j^k=\delta_j^k, \forall j,k \\
   &\Leftrightarrow e^i\delta_i^j=1, \forall j \\
   &\Leftrightarrow e^j=1, \forall j
   \end{alignat}
   Thus, $\bar e=(1,1,\dots,1)$ is multiplicative unit.
2. ***[Any name for this?]***. This is the case for:

$$\alpha_{ij}^k=\delta_{i+j-1}^k \tag 2$$

The element $\bar e \in R^n$ is multiplicative unit if and only if:

\begin{alignat}{1}
\bar e_j=\bar e \times \bar e_j=e^i\bar e_i \times \bar e_j=e^i\alpha_{ij}^k\bar e_k, \forall j &\Leftrightarrow e^i\delta_{i+j-1}^k=\delta_j^k, \forall j,k \\
&\Leftrightarrow e^{k-j+1}=\delta_j^k, \forall j,k, j \le k \\
&\Leftrightarrow (e^{k-j+1}=0, 1 \le j < k \le n) \wedge (e^1=1) \\
&\Leftrightarrow (e^{k-j+1}=0, 1 \le k-j \le n-1) \wedge (e^1=1) \\
&\Leftrightarrow (e^m=0, 2 \le m \le n) \wedge (e^1=1) \\
\end{alignat}

Thus, $\bar e=(1,0,\dots,0)$ is multiplicative unit.

My question is: Given $R$ and $n$, how particular/exaustive are $(1)$ and $(2)$ in defining all the possible ring classes(?) $(R^n,+,\times)$?

Comment: Not at all exhaustive. If you don't require your ring structure to be either associative or unital, any choice of $\alpha_{ij}^k$ determines a ring structure on $R^n$.

Comment: Your second ring is $R[x]/(x^{n})$.

Comment: Thank you for your overall feedback. Let me add one more question: what if I had put in $(2)$ $i+j-1\mod n$?

Comment: Then it would be $R[x]/(x^n-1)$